# API REST CON PHP

Tags: php, api, rest

Hola estoy queriendo  realizar una api rest con php y me encontré con el problema que numero selecciona perfectamente la consulta pero string o alfanumérico me da error les dejo mi código a ver si me pueden ayudar desde ya gracias.(es un crud simple quiero seleccionar por código del producto que aveces es alfanumérico)

```
<?php 
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");


  header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');

  header('Content-Type: application/json');


  require("../model/db.php"); // IMPORTA EL ARCHIVO CON LA CONEXION A LA DB

  $conexion = conexion(); // CREA LA CONEXION

  // REALIZA LA QUERY A LA DB
  $registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE codigo=($_GET[codigo])");

  // SI EL USUARIO EXISTE OBTIENE LOS DATOS Y LOS GUARDA EN UN ARRAY
  while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($registros))  
  {
    $datos[]= $resultado;
  }
  $json=array();
  echo json_encode($datos);

?>
```

Comment: Que error te genera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta cambiar esto:

```
$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE codigo=($_GET[codigo])");
```

Por esto:

```
$cod = $_GET['codigo'];    
$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE codigo='$cod' ");
```

Comment: Por favor explica que cambiar y por qué pues solo poner código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Este código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Se recomienda usar consultas preparadas, ya que un usuario mal intencionado podría provocar daños irreparables en los datos o en el sistema mismo.